Connection between reordering and memory barrier
I thought typically memory barriers can be categorized into four types.
Some of the barriers include multiple functions.
For example, StoreLoad can both prevent reordering between store and load, and drain the store buffer.
These two functions are seemingly irrelevant to each other, so I wonder why they are combined into one instruction.
In other words, why do we not use two individual instructions, one for draining store buffer and another for preventing reordering?
I know there must be some intrinsic connection, but I cannot figure it out myself, so I posted this question.
I appreciate any suggestions and guidance.

The store buffer is an optimization technique that can lead to reordering of the memory accesses seen from other cores. This however is independent of the reordering concept itself. Reordering can happen for other reasons too. A memory barrier must fit the actual microarchitectural optimizations implemented, so you will often see memory barriers do more that just stall later memory accesses. The goal of a memory barrier is to make stores and/or loads visible to other agents before the next ones. Depending on the agents involved, the CPU may need to flush intermediary caches/buffers

@MargaretBloom Thank you! Can I say that composite function (prevent reorder and stall memory access) of memory barrier is dependent on microachitecture? If so, is there any keywords for serarching further concrete information? Thank you again for your kindness.

Memory barriers are about the order in which accesses become visible to other cores in the system, not merely the order in which they are executed.  So if you want a StoreLoad barrier, you are asking for all earlier stores to become visible before all later loads, and naturally the store buffer must be drained in order to achieve that.

@NateEldredge thank you! I see it is necessary to drain the store buffer for StoreLoad, but why does it prevent reordering subsequent loads before the barrier? I thought (mistakenly) that the core issuing the barrier would get the correct value because of the store forwarding, even though the loads were reordered before the barrier and after the store.

The store buffer can create StoreLoad reordering, but seeing your own stores before other cores see them is sort of a separate effect.  (Related: Globally Invisible load instructions).  On x86 at least (and I assume all mainstream ISAs), a full-barrier instruction blocks later loads entirely until the store buffer drains, regardless of what they'd read.  This makes it possible to recover sequential consistency on top of an otherwise-weaker HW memory model. Allowing later loads to get as far as checking for forwarding cache vs. fwding would be hard.
